# Scala: Generic Method

Tags: scala, types, slick

I can not find a solution to this problem:

This trait:

```
trait BasicRepository[Schema <: Table[Entity] with Identifiable[Entity], Entity]
```

And this:

```
trait ProfilePartRepository[Schema <: Table[Entity] with ProfilePart[Entity], Entity]
```

This object:

```
 object PhoneNumberRepository extends BasicRepository[PhoneNumbers, PhoneNumber] with ProfilePartRepository[PhoneNumbers, PhoneNumber] {
```

And this method:

```
def insertProfilePart[Schema <: Table[Entity] with Identifiable[Entity], Entity](repository: BasicRepository[Schema, Entity], entities: Seq[Entity]) : Seq[Future[Int]]
```

The method does not compile. But I think you can see what I would like to achieve. What does the signature have to look like?

EDIT: Actually I do not care about "Schema" in the Method, it just has to be a valid BasicRepository.

EDIT2: Compilation Error (when calling the method, with AgnosticDriver.api being slick.driver.JdbcDriver):

```
 inferred type arguments [persistence.slickSchemas.PhoneNumbers,Product with Serializable] do not conform to method insertProfilePart's type parameter bounds [Schema <: persistence.AgnosticDriver.api.Table[Entity] with persistence.slickSchemas.Identifiable[Entity],Entity]
```

Comment: what is the compilation error?

Comment: Added to question:
inferred type arguments [persistence.slickSchemas.PhoneNumbers,Product with Serializable] do not conform to method insertProfilePart's type parameter bounds [Schema <: persistence.AgnosticDriver.api.Table[Entity] with persistence.slickSchemas.Identifiable[Entity],Entity]

Comment: From eyeballing the question I don't see why it gives you hard time. Is it possible to a create standalone (compilable) version of the code that reproduces the error? Then someone can at least experiment a bit around to see what is going in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so thanks for the comments. I was too stupid to read to think about the easy failures.

I just passed the wrong arguments to "insertProfilePart" ...